# How to show the content in drupal on the basis of taxonomy and node type(content type) in drupal 7?

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, drupal-7

My purpose is to develop course module in drupal 7
Whenever student will logging , he will see the list of all courses.
Student have to join the course after that he will see all the details of joined course.
Each and every course will have its own home page having some menu links like
***Home,Videos,documents,forum (Forum for this course only),Search(This will search within this course)***
For joining any course I have used sign up module ....
How can I manage these things ..... Please suggest me as soon as possible.

Comment: There are many ways the content can be presented in Drupal. You can have a look at Views module to start with.

Comment: Can you please suggest me that how can I manage these things with views module ....?